# Logging standard output with Payara/Glassfish

Tags: glassfish, outputstream, payara

A J2ee application writes some debugging data on standard output. It runs on Payara 5.2 server  which is configured to write standard streams to **domains/myDomain/log/myLogName.log** but I cannot find the messages there. I'm sure I could read those messages in the log with an old version of Glassfish (may be 4.1), the configuration changed a bit since then, but apparently the current one is correct. What should I check ? Could it be a bug ?

Update 1

After a month I still have no idea why the logging system is not working. I compared **domain.xml** with a similar one in another server where logging is working as expected and found no relevant differences.
All messages sent to standard output and standard error are lost. In the Server.log file I can only find messages from Payara server itself, nothing form the applications it contains.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior was very weird, Payara was not logging what was printed on System.out, and it was not a configuration issue. Some applications are running on this Payara server and one of them has the following debugging code:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind;
...
ObjectMapper myMapper = new ObjectMapper();
myMapper.writeValue(System.out, myObject);
```

In the API description of method **writeValue** there is the following note:

> Note: method does not close the underlying stream explicitly here; however, JsonFactory this mapper uses may choose to close the stream depending on its settings (by default, it will try to close it when JsonGenerator we construct is closed).

So Payara logging was erroneously and unexpectedly stopped by this application.
Easy to understand, not so easy to find out !

I didn't even know it was possible to close **System.out**, it is something you don't do by purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to display the System out on payara console logs. You could enable the "Logging Standard Streams" to be able to include print out you want to see on your logs.

You can see this options to "Configuration" >> "server-config" >> "Logger Settings". by enabling it you can see also the active streams on you application server.

check this image for your guide.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hplv1.jpg

Also do take note that enabling it will produce a lot more logs on your server. So it will consume more storage in the long run. I suggest to enable it if you want to debug something on your application server.